# Jquery background slide show with gallery

Tags: jquery-plugins

Does anyone know of a jquery plugin that has a background slide show and a gallery that changes background images every time someone opens the site or every hour or so?

Comment: You can find many slideshow scripts with little bit googling. When you have some in hand, but can't get it to do what you want you can post specific question here. Thats how you will get help from Stackoverflow

Answer (score 0):

There are lot of jQuery slideshow plugins. I would recommend you to look at the following:

Slide JS - http://www.slidesjs.com/

```
<head>
        <title>Title</title>

        <style type="text/css" media="screen">
            .slides_container {
                width:570px;
                height:270px;
            }
            .slides_container div {
                width:570px;
                height:270px;
                display:block;
            }
        </style>

        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
        <script src="slides.js"></script>

        <script>
            $(function(){
                $("#slides").slides();
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="slides">
            <div class="slides_container">
                <div>
                    <img src="http://placehold.it/570x270">
                </div>
                <div>
                    <img src="http://placehold.it/570x270">
                </div>
                <div>
                    <img src="http://placehold.it/570x270">
                </div>
                <div>
                    <img src="http://placehold.it/570x270">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
```

Also, check some good slideshow plugins [here](http://vandelaydesign.com/blog/web-development/jquery-slideshow/)